# install colorama python module

Tags: drivers, python

I import colorama in python code and I have below error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "stevoku.py", line 5, in <module>
import colorama
ImportError: No module named colorama
```

and I install colorama and I too this error.
I install colorama :

```
apt-get install python-colorama
```

Answer (score 3):

Install it using `pip`

```
sudo pip install colorama
```

If you don't have pip read [How to install pip for python 3 in ubuntu 12.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412178/how-to-install-pip-for-python-3-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts)

---

Another way is to download colorama module from [here](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/colorama/colorama-0.3.3.tar.gz).

Now extract the package

```
cd colorama*
```

Then run

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: how to install pip in Ubuntu ?

Comment: Extract with `tar xf colorama-0.3.3.tar.gz`. Install `pip` with `sudo apt-get install python-pip` and/or `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:
Install it by using:

```
sudo apt-get install python-colorama
```

You need `sudo` if you want to use `apt-get`.