# unable to download using youtube-dl

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-dl

I am unable to download videos from Youtube using `youtube-dl`. Below is the code. Please help!

```
root@itzamlan10:~# sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
youtube-dl is already the newest version.

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 82 not upgraded.
root@itzamlan10:~#
root@itzamlan10:~# youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2wNvUHBVw5U
[youtube] 2wNvUHBVw5U: Downloading webpage
ERROR: Unable to download webpage: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests (caused by HTTPError()); please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug .
Make sure you are using the latest version; type  youtube-dl -U  to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its com
plete output.
```

Comment: I have version `2015.07.04`. Maybe you need to uninstall your olde version and update from `http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl` because the one in the repo is old.

Comment: Please read the message and act on it:  Downloading webpage ERROR: Unable to download webpage: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests (caused by HTTPError()); please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug  This is NOT an Ubuntu related problem; it is an issue with that website.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is almost certainly because you're running an older version of `youtube-dl`.

You should uninstall the apt version with

```
apt-get purge youtube-dl
```

and then install it with pip instead.

```
pip3 install youtube-dl
```

If you don't have pip3, you can install it with,

```
apt-get install python3-pip
```

or see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412178/how-to-install-pip-for-python-3-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts) for more help on that.

The `youtube-dl` package in the apt repo for jessie(and maybe even trusty) hasn't been updated in almost a year.

Comment: it's not working.

Comment: @VirtualTravels Do you still have the same error? Has anything changed since the last time?

Comment: no. it's the same error.

Comment: @VirtualTravels Can you add the output of `which youtube-dl` and `youtube-dl --version` to your question?

Comment: it's the same error.

Comment: @VirtualTravels I'm sure. It would help if you could add that information. I'm trying to make sure you're running the right build. Also, the output from the command mentions running it with the `--verbose` flag. If you could add the output of that, that'd be great.

Comment: Hi @Kasisnu could you please try to download a youtube video. And let us know the set of commands you executed for that. That could be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, 429 means that you may have downloaded too much. Practically, this is very common problem running youtube-dl on OVH/AWS/etc. You may want to workaround this by using `--proxy` or `--source-address` (see [youtube-dl FAQ](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl#http-error-429-too-many-requests-or-402-payment-required)). You may also want to read [this thread](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/5138).

Comment: Ah, you might be right about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding '-4' or '-6' flags for forcing the download over IPv4 and IPv6 respectively. 
The video you were trying to download is unavailable now but the following command works for me :

```
youtube-dl -4 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJFgo9H6zNo
```

You can refer [this thread](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/5138) for more information.