# trying to install mysql-connector for python 3

Tags: software-installation, python, mysql, python3

my experience is minimal with Linux so i need a little help!

i am trying to install the python mysql-connector for python3.2, i was able to use pip to install it for python2.7 with 'pip install mysql-connector'. To install it for python 3 i believe you have to use the python3 pip instead of the python2 pip, i read that somewhere but im not sure if its correct, does the python3 pip know to get the correct connector or do you have to specify the specific version like 'pip install mysql-connector1.2'.

anyways, i was finding it difficult to get the py3 pip, then i came across a post advising the use of 'virtualenv' to make it easier to work with different versions of python. This post:

[How to install pip for python 3 in ubuntu 12.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412178/how-to-install-pip-for-python-3-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts)

says to create the virtual environment, activate it and then proceed to pip install whatever package you need. however, when i get as far as pip install it doesnt seem to get the mysql-connector that i need, and running 'pip --version' from inside the virtualenv it tells me that the python2.7 pip is being used.

i've tried other things to try get pip3 such as 'easy-install pip3' which doesnt seem to work either.

Is this the only route to take to get the correct mysql-connector? or is there another way i can get pip3 (for py3.2)?

thanks, any advice greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah! The problem you seem to be facing is you can't create virtualenv with python3.

And to install dependencies for `python3` environment you run `pip3 install package-name`

Follow these steps for creating virtualenv in python3 environment:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 yourenv
source yourenv/bin/activate
pip3 install mysql-connector
```

Answer (score 7):

`sudo apt-get install python3-mysql.connector`
or
    `pip3 install mysql-connector`

this will install mysql.connector for python3 on ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

Just install pip for python3:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

And afterwards your can use pip3 as yask comments:

```
pip3 install mysql-connector
```

Comment: OP is using Ubuntu 12.04, and `python3-pip` is only available on 14.04 onwards