# How to install MySQL community as well as MySQL and Python connectivity?

Tags: python, mysql

Laptop: Dell Vostro 3590
Ubuntu version: 23.10
How do I install MySQL and well as connectivity to it with Python?

Comment: these already answer both parts: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232558/install-mysql-5-7-on-ubuntu-20-04 explains most of your question.  and https://askubuntu.com/questions/656610/trying-to-install-mysql-connector-for-python-3#:~:text=https%3A//askubuntu.com/a/754389/15811 your 2nd part. If you run into trouble following those topics ask about the issue if it not already has an answer on AU :)

Answer (score 0):

**Update Package Index:**

```
sudo apt update
```

- Install MySQL Server:
  You can install MySQL Server package using the following command:
- `sudo apt install mysql-server`

Once the installation is complete, the MySQL server should be started automatically. You can quickly check its current status via systemd:

`sudo service mysql status`

**Further steps: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-python/latest/installation.html**