# Trouble during 'pip' install

Tags: software-installation, python3, pip

I need help for the installtion of `pip`.

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-colorama
 python-distlib
 python-ndg-httpsclient
 python-urllib3
 python-requests
 python-setuptools
 python-pip
 python-wheel
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

In addition:

```
$ pip -V
bash: /usr/bin/pip: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

Comment: I suppressed your Django tag because it seems not to be related to the content of yr post. Please edit yr question to include the step you used to install pip. Also mention the version of yr Ubuntu system.

Comment: How did you try yo install it? What's the full output of the command(s)? Also, you tagged the question with [tag:python3], but the package manager output only mentions `python-pip`. What's the output of `sudo apt-get install -f python-pip` (replace with `python3-pip` if you prefer)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install pip for python 3 in ubuntu 12.04 LTS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/412178/how-to-install-pip-for-python-3-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts)

Answer (score 0):

pip is installed when you have either python2.x or anaconda installed.
You can install anaconda from this [link](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)

Once you have got the installer run it like this

```
bash ~/Downloads/Anaconda3-2.4.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

After installation pip is also installed

```
which pip
/opt/anaconda2/bin/pip
```

Comment: Yes, but I would favor @DavidFoerster's install path. It's lighter on the OS in case Anaconda is not specifically needed .  The result of `which pip` in David's case would be `/usr/bin/pip`.