# "Unable to locate package python-pip" When trying to install from fresh 18.04 install

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, python

I was following a tutorial online for python and it had me do this:

```
akclark@enceladus:~$ pip install virtualenv
```

But I got the following:

```
Command 'pip' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install python-pip
```

Easy enough, right? So I try it..

```
akclark@enceladus:~$ sudo apt install python-pip
```

But I get an error...

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-pip
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Per Comments I have tried `sudo apt update`

EDIT2: I tried `apt-cache madison python-pip` and got

```
N: Unable to locate package python-pip
```

EDIT3: `grep '^deb ' /etc/apt/sources.list` showed

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main
```

Comment: `sudo apt update` then try again: `sudo apt install python-pip`

Comment: Done. Same result. =(

Comment: what is the output of `apt-cache madison python-pip`? edit your question add the output.

Comment: N: Unable to locate package python-pip

Comment: Also `grep '^deb ' /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: I updated the question to show the output.

Comment: **BEWARE!** Ubuntu's `pip` can cause bizarre conflicts and shouldn't be used for system packages anyway. You might well want a local install of a modern `pip` (version 18 and beyond), and use it only with `--user`. See [ImportError in system pip wrappers after an upgrade · Issue #5599 · pypa/pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You have to enable `universe` category which contains `python-pip` package.

As David suggested, if you have `software-properties-common` installed, You can use this command to add `universe` category to your sources file:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Then:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python-pip
```

However if you rather to add it manually or you don't have `add-apt-repository` command available to run then follow these instructions:

Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` using an editor, for example `nano`:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then add  `universe` at the end of each line, like this:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main universe 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main universe
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save the file.
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to quit nano.

then run:

```
sudo apt update
```

and finally:

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```